# How to host office add-in on nodeJS server

Tags: office-js

So I want to host a custom office add in on a nodeJS server.

How do I go about doing this, the instructions from Microsoft seem pretty vague other than ['deploy your add-in on a web server'](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins) or ['Specify the web site address'](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/set-up-an-add-in-catalog-on-office-365).

Basically, how should I host the manifest XML, html and js files on a nodeJS server so that I can access it in word/excel/whatever?

Answer (score 5):

You don't host the manifest. You deploy it to a catalog. See the topics in this branch of the help: [Deploy and publish Office Add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish)

You host the HTML/JS files, with a NodeJS server if you like. This is no different than hosting any other web application on a NodeJS server, with the additional requirement that you must enable HTTPS for the server. Consult the official documentation for NodeJS or the documentation of any of the servers that can be hosted in NodeJS, such as LiteServer.

After you have determined what the domain of your server will be, you need to edit the manifest so that all the URLs in the manifest point to that domain instead of the localhost domain that you use when developing.